# Visual Studio 2015 Test explorer starts multiple projects on build

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2015, test-explorer

I have a C# solution in Visual Studio 2015 with several projects, and some of them are Windows Forms tools, which are all built when I rebuild the solution.

The problem is, if my Test Explorer tool window is docked (open) when I do a rebuild (only a rebuild, not Start with/without debugging), all Windows Forms projects are started (begin executing) at once - similar to what I would get if I chose multiple startup projects and clicked Start.

Is this a known issue, or a result of some incorrect configuration on my side? I don't remember having this issue earlier.

Comment: Can you clarify "all forms are started at once " - do you mean "all form builds are started at once" ?

Comment: @PhillipH: no, all applications are actually executed as soon as the build is finished. If the Test Explorer is closed, build just finishes as usual. Meaning I get (say) four Windows Forms apps running all of a sudden, just by rebuilding.

Comment: At the same time, Test explorer progress bar is rotating, and after a while test begin executing in the Test Explorer.

Comment: Do you have a test that executes your application or shows a form?

Comment: @SergeyL: No, tests don't start any apps, just plain unit tests defined in separate testing projects in the same solution. Most of these forms projects are UI only and are not even referenced by unit test projects.

Comment: You don't have the test settings set to "Run Tests After Build" as referenced here http://dailydotnettips.com/2015/06/12/run-tests-after-build-automatically-running-unit-test-after-build-success-in-visual-studio/ ? Its not a solution but I wonder if it might be part of the problem.

Comment: @PhillipH: actually, I don't have this option in VS2015 Community. But I also don't remember this happening earlier, so I have a feeling some weird setting got changed somewhere.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found out the offending plugin: it's the [GoogleTest Runner](https://github.com/markusl/GoogleTestRunner) extension, which discovers C/C++ unit tests by running any executables built by the solution which match `[Tt]est[s]{0,1}.*.exe`.

Incidentally, some .NET apps in the solution were named something like `ConnectionTester`, so they were getting executed by the plugin (it would pass certain arguments through the command line), which expected they would return a list of tests to run. It would be cool if the plugin at least checked the type/language of the project before running it, so I will try to submit a patch for this as soon as I get a spare moment.